# Generating random point inside a cylinder?

Tags: math, geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating random point in a cylinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203382/generating-random-point-in-a-cylinder)

How to generate a random point inside a circular cylinder if radius r and height h are given?

particularly inside the cylinder not on the cylinder

Comment: Just to be clear... "Inside" meaning a point anywhere in the volume of the cylinder, or a random point on the surface?

Comment: @ Adam S :anywhere in the volume of the cylinder

Comment: @user1198477 this question is very soon going to get closed as an exact duplicate of the one you asked 6 days ago. Is there anything *different* this time? If so, you should edit your question to say what.

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
angle = Random(0, 2*Pi)
r1 = r * sqrt( Random(0,1) )
X = r1*sin(angle)
Y = r1*cos(angle)
Z = Random(0,h)
```

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz, why do you have sqrt?  Wouldn't you just want a random radius between 0 and r?

Comment: [Edited to clarify:] You need to take r * the sqrt of the random number, not sqrt(r*random()).  Say r were 5 -- then sqrt(5*random()) would never be greater than sqrt(5).

Comment: @DSM : do you mean r1= r* sqrt(Random(0,1)) in the above mentioned code

Comment: @DSM Agreed, you need r1=r*sqrt( Random(0,1) ) in this answer. TJD you need sqrt to avoid getting a bigger concentration of points near the centre

Comment: Here's a nice blurb explaining the significance of needing square root: http://www.anderswallin.net/2009/05/uniform-random-points-in-a-circle-using-polar-coordinates/