# How do I revolve points around a mesh?

Tags: javascript, three.js, point

I'm trying to use Three.js to generate some points with [`Three.Points`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/Points), and then make the points themselves revolve around a single point (or mesh). I've generated the points randomly in a cylinder region as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9203691/5647260) answer and reviewed posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214582/how-do-i-rotate-some-moons-around-a-planet-with-three-js) one, which doesn't seem to work as it's rotating a mesh around a mesh.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
//Mesh that is to be revolved around
const blackHoleGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10, 64, 64);

const blackHoleMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x000000
});

const blackHole = new THREE.Mesh(blackHoleGeometry, blackHoleMaterial);
scene.add(blackHole);

//Points that are supposed to revolve around the mesh

const particles = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff
});

const geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

// [...] code to generate random points

const pointCloud = new THREE.Points(geometry, particles);
pointCloud.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2; //to rotate it 90*
```

You can see a full demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pwwkght0/). How can I have the points all revolve around the sphere mesh, as in each vertex of the point "cloud"'s geometry revolving around a center point, or the mesh like a planet and a star?

Comment: Er, what do you mean by "rotate around a mesh"? By definition, you can't rotate points around anything other than a line (though that line may be defined by a point and the point you're rotating).

Comment: I think that your terminology might be what's tripping you up. Your black hole is a sphere, but you can't 'rotate' around a sphere, you need an axis.
if your axis passes through your sphere's centre point then it'll _look_ like it orbits the sphere. This might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060734/how-to-rotate-a-3d-object-on-axis-three-js

Comment: @QPaysTaxes What would happen if you rotate a point about the line defined by a point and the point itself? _Exactly! The point won't move at all._

Comment: @Ben Thanks so much for the link and the info!

Comment: @frederick99 Er, I'm confused. Were you trying to ping Andrew?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes **though that line may be defined by a point and the point you're rotating** I think I pinged the right guy. ;)

Comment: @frederick99 Right. "may". As in, not "has to". See [RFC2119](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple problems with you code, but here is an updated fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/pwwkght0/2/

So when you create your Three.js scene you want to keep all of your code in the `init` function. So I moved everything in there and then I called `init` outside of the variable. When you do this, `init` will create you scene until it reaches the last line and call `animate`. You want to call `animate` instead of `render` because animate will request animation frames and call `render` on each.

```
function init() {
    //do all the things to make the scene

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        orbit();
        controls.update();
        render();
    }

    function render() {
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    animate();
}

init()
```

So now that you are requesting animation frames, it's time to make things orbit. I made a very simple function to grab your point cloud and rotate it on its z-axis, to simulate it rotating around the sphere. Notice how `orbit` is called in `animate`:

```
function orbit() {
    pointCloud.rotation.z += 0.01;
}
```

You can take this a step further and have each point rotate at a different speed around the sphere by accessing `pointCloud`'s children property.